# Python function that will graph the tangent plane to a 3d surface function

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, graphing, calculus

I need to create a function that graphs the tangent plane to a 3d function at a specific point. Here is the type of thing it needs to take in:

```
# test case 1
plot_tan_plane(lambda x,y: 3 - x**2 - y**2,1,1)
```

and it needs to output a graph like this:

[here is a picture of what the output should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lgaI.png)

Here is the code I have so far but it is giving me errors:
    from sympy import symbols, diff

```
def plot_tan_plane(f,a,b):

    g = f

    x = y = np.linspace(-5,5,50)

    X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y) # this basically makes all the pairs on coordinates

    # Set up axes. There are so many ways to do this.
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
    ax = plt.subplot(projection='3d')

    a = a
    b = b

    h = 0.1
    q = (g(a,b))
    s = (g(a+h,b))

    u= (g(a,b+h))

    v = (s/h)-(q/h)
    w = (u/h)-(q/h)
    z = (lambda x,y: q + v*(X-a) + w*(Y-b),a,b)

    i = lambda x,y: z
    j = lambda x,y: g


    #do the plotting
    ax.plot_surface(X,Y,i);
    ax.plot_surface(X,Y,j);
```

This is the error it is giving me:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-a24f1f7bed99> in <module>
      1 # test case 1
----> 2 plot_tan_plane(lambda x,y: 3 - x**2 - y**2,1,1)

<ipython-input-95-85e008d4abd6> in plot_tan_plane(f, a, b)
     33 
     34     #do the plotting
---> 35     ax.plot_surface(X,Y,i);
     36     ax.plot_surface(X,Y,j);
     37 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py in plot_surface(self, X, Y, Z, norm, vmin, vmax, lightsource, *args, **kwargs)
   1611         had_data = self.has_data()
   1612 
-> 1613         if Z.ndim != 2:
   1614             raise ValueError("Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.")
   1615         if np.any(np.isnan(Z)):

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Can you fix the indentation? Select the code/function and type `ctrl-k` .. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Please read [mcve] - How are you calling the function? What are you passing to it? What is `f`, `a`, `b`?

Comment: `i = lambda x,y: z`  - You are passing a function for a parameter that is expecting a 2-d array - should you be calling it `ax.plot_surface(X,Y,i())` - https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots

Comment: This lambda - `z = (lambda x,y: q + v*(X-a) + w*(Y-b),a,b)` - excepts an argument for `x` and `y` yet it never uses them - why?

Comment: Did you write the code? What is the purpose of `a=a` and `b=b`? Why are you using so many lambda functions and never calling them? What is `i = lambda x,y: z` supposed to do? Your example is missing some imports; it is throwing a number of exceptions - please read [mcve]. Why didn't you create the axes like the example in the documentation - `ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')`??